# Using realloc inside a function

Tags: c, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

My apologies, I know many related questions have already been asked, so I will keep it very simple.

Despite some years of programming I cannot find the correct syntax for resizing and modifying an array (or several) inside a function. For example, say I want a function to fill an array with a set of "n" numbers, where "n" is defined within the array:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float *data = NULL
    int n = myfunction(data);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%f\n",data[i]);
    free(data);
}

int myfunction(float *input) {
    int i,n=10;
    input = (float *) realloc( input, n*sizeof(float) );
    if(input!=NULL) {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) input[i] = (float)i;
        return(n);
    else return(-1)
}
```

I know this will not work, as I probably need to use a pointer to a pointer, but I cannot resolve which combination of pointers, pointers-to-pointers, and address notation to use inside and outside the function to use.

Any simple suggestions appreciated!

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: fair comment, but not quite what i was looking for ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to a pointer to `myFunction`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myfunction(float **input) {
    int i,n=10;
    *input = realloc( *input, n*sizeof(float) );
    if(*input!=NULL) {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) (*input)[i] = (float)i;
        return(n);
    }
    else return(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float *data = NULL;
    int n = myfunction(&data);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%f\n",data[i]);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! If I were explaining it to someone else, I'd say you need to pass the address of the array, tell the function to treat it as a pointer-to-a-pointer, and within the function refer to the pointer itself when using realloc() or assigning values. Cheers!

Comment: What if there are already values in the array? `realloc` in principle copies the values, but it is done in the function. Do the values get lost in this way?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to pass the old pointer to `myfunction()`, and have it return the new pointer (which might be the same as the old, if `realloc()` managed to grow the area in-place).

Note that `realloc()` can fail, in that case you don't want to lose track of the old memory which is still allocated so overwriting the same pointer without checking is a bad idea.

Comment: I appreciate your point and I do exactly that in other circumstances but the "real" program is a helluva lot more complex than the simple example I posted, and requires modification of two or more arrays, growing each of them with realloc() as needed.